# Ionic 3.1.1 using ionViewCanEnter with push did not catch the false response

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Before upgrading to Ionic 3.1.1 from Ionic 3.0.1 this problem does not exist.

After upgrading to Ionic 3.1.1 pushing to a page with the NavGuard, the navCtrl.push().catch did not catch the error.

In my RequestPage I have this NavGuard written:

```
ionViewCanEnter():boolean {
   return this.auth.authUser();
}
```

In my homePage I have this push to the RequestPage

```
pushRequest() {
  this.navCtrl.push('RequestPage')
    .catch(()=> this.pushLogin());
}
```

This should pop up the login page, but now has no effect at all, and no errors either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging for an answer I see this is being added to milestone of Ionic 3.2.0 on github, I guess this is an issue since Ionic 3.1.0

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/11433

Comment: I've opened the issue, but I'm not sure if it's an issue or the docs should be updated. Just in case, the catch is not being fired, but you can handle the _false_ scenario by checking the result in the `then` callback like this: `this.navCtrl.push('RequestPage').then(result => { if(!result) { /* the same as the catch here*/ } })`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am doing right now, if you check your issue, the dev had added this to the milestone of Ionic 3.2.0, I guess it's is an issue after all, but they are planning to fix it in 3.2.0.